# How to get the remaining indexes after a random set of indexes is selected in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, random, numpy-ndarray

Use the following code to illustrate my question.

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(200)
a = np.array([1,21,6,41,8]) # given an array with 5 elements
idx = np.random.choice(5, 3, replace=False) # randomly select 3 indexes between 0 and 4
idx.sort() # sort indexes
print(idx) # [0 3 4]
print(a[idx]) # get random selected subset using the indexes, [ 1 41  8]
```

How to get the remaining indexes [1,2]?

Comment: you can create a new list `remaining = [x for x in range(5) if x not in idx]` or just pop the random indexes from a list with all indexes

Answer (score 1):

```
In [123]: np.random.seed(200)
     ...: a = np.array([1,21,6,41,8]) # given an array with 5 elements
     ...: idx = np.random.choice(5, 3, replace=False) # randomly select 3 indexe
     ...: s between 0 and 4
     ...: idx.sort() # sort indexes
In [124]: idx
Out[124]: array([0, 3, 4])
In [125]: a[idx]
Out[125]: array([ 1, 41,  8])
```

We could make a boolean `mask`, and find the True indices:

```
In [126]: mask = np.ones(a.shape, bool)
In [127]: mask[idx]=False
In [128]: mask
Out[128]: array([False,  True,  True, False, False])
In [129]: np.nonzero(mask)[0]
Out[129]: array([1, 2])

In [131]: np.arange(a.shape[0])[mask]
Out[131]: array([1, 2])
```

`np.delete` does this same sort of masking:

```
In [132]: np.delete(np.arange(a.shape[0]), idx)
Out[132]: array([1, 2])
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it:

```
inverted_idx = [x not in idx for x in range(0, len(a))]
print(a[inverted_idx])
```

Result:

```
[21  6]
```

That creates a boolean mask, if you prefer an integer mask, like the one you had:

```
inverted_idx = [x for x in range(0, len(a)) if x not in idx]
print(a[inverted_idx])
```